# Add/remove class based on checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have a small form that is kind of working. There are 2 options, `A` and `B`.

If `A` and `B` are `NO` then disable the button. If `A` OR `B` are `YES` then remove the `disable` class from the button. That's what I'm aiming for, this is what I have:

```
$('.check-opt').change(function () {
  if ($('input[name="step_2"],[name="step_4"]:checked').val() == "yes") {
    $('#order_btn_id').removeClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#order_btn_id').addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

It's kind of working in the sense that it removes the disabled class when choosing `A` OR `B`, but when you select both `A` and `B` as `NO` then the disabled class isn't added back in. Where have I gone wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can use `toggleClass` instead of add/remove class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with your logic is that you're calling `val()` on a collection of elements, so it will only read the value of the first one.

The easiest way to achieve what you need is to use `toggleClass()` along with a boolean to determine if the class should be added or removed. You can set the state of that boolean depending on whether or not both checkboxes are unchecked, like this:

```js
$('.check-opt').change(function() {
  var disabled = !$('input[name="step_2"]').prop('checked') && !$('input[name="step_4"]').prop('checked');
  $('#order_btn_id').toggleClass('disabled', disabled);
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="step_2" class="check-opt" />
<input type="checkbox" name="step_4" class="check-opt" />
<button id="order_btn_id" class="disabled">Order</button>
```

This could potentially be simplified to check if any `.check-opt` element is checked, but this depends on how many groups of checkboxes you have in the DOM:

```
var disabled = $('.check-opt:checked').length == 0;
```

Also note that if you want to completely disable the button it would be worth setting `prop('disabled', true)` as well as adding the class to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use two selectors for your query:

```
var a = $('input[name="step_2"]:checked').val() == "yes";
var b = $('[name="step_4"]:checked').val() == "yes";

$('#order_btn_id').toggleClass('disabled', a || b)
```